# Почему вызов метода из ТЕСТА и вызов метода из MAIN отрабатывают по разному?

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, pdf, junit

Есть проблема, которая сломала мне голову.

Мне необходимо вытащить данные из ПДФа и встроить их в структуру. Нашел одну опен-сорс [библиотеку](https://github.com/eadgyo/Extract-PDF-Excel), которая отлично конвертирует пдф файл в эксель. НО!!!

При вызове метода этой библиотеки из main -> отрабатывает как надо и все работает. В случае запуска теста-кейса, который вызывает этот метод, он исполняется и на каком-то этапе выбрасывает AssertionError при прочих равных. Не понимаю с чем это может быть связано. Библиотека крайне важна для проекта. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться в чем здесь дело.

Метод:

```
PdfConverter.createExcelSheets("src/main/resources/document.pdf", workbook);
```

Трейс:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
at org.eadge.extractpdfexcel.data.array.My2DArray.insertLine(My2DArray.java:155)
at org.eadge.extractpdfexcel.data.array.My2DArray.insertLine(My2DArray.java:187)
at org.eadge.extractpdfexcel.data.array.My2DArray.addLine(My2DArray.java:176)
at org.eadge.extractpdfexcel.data.SortedPage.create2DArrayOfBlocks(SortedPage.java:113)
at org.eadge.extractpdfexcel.PdfConverter.createExcelPage(PdfConverter.java:331)
at org.eadge.extractpdfexcel.PdfConverter.createExcelPages(PdfConverter.java:313)
at org.eadge.extractpdfexcel.PdfConverter.createExcelSheets(PdfConverter.java:414)
at org.eadge.extractpdfexcel.PdfConverter.createExcelSheets(PdfConverter.java:437)
at myTest.testExtract(myTest.java:12)
```

Comment: прикрепите, пожалуйста, код и описание ошибки

Comment: @azlov Добавил в пост. Контекст не важен, т.к при сухом вызове метода в мэине/тесте происходит описанная проблема.

Comment: Код теста тоже прикрепите

Comment: @FirstSin код теста выглядит как вызов одного вышеуказанного метода, больше ничего кроме

Answer (score 0):

Если посмотреть стектрейс, то мы прийдем к методу `My2DArray.insertLine` в 155 строке

собственно, там этот код. этот ассерт падает, а значит в main и test вы передаете разные параметры в pdf converter

нужно подебажить код библиотеки и посмотреть что приходит в качестве insertIndex в main и test. Скорее всего (даже точно), там будут разные значения. Выясним, откуда и почему приходит insertIndex <= 0 в test, Вы поймете в чем дело

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, я понимаю что на этом ассерте он выкидывает еррор. Но ведь при вызове и там и там передается абсолютно одинаковый путь до файла. Вы не пробовали вызывать этот метод из теста и непосредственно из программы?

Comment: @witi поверьте, видно ли файл из тестов и из main. возможно, где-то его просто не видно